# Is there a topic, branch, operation in math to systematically express an equation as a matrix?

Tags: matrices, parametric, nomography

I'm trying to find a topic to study on that would deal on expressing equations as matrices determinants. Let me explain.

Let's say I have the equation:

x - 2y + 2z = 0

I can write the above equation in matrix form as:

$$
det \begin{bmatrix} x & 0 & 2 \\ z & 1 & 0 \\  y & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = 0
$$

Is there anyway to create this matrix not being by trial and error? Is there a name for this operation? Maybe I'm cracking my head on something that Wolfram could give me the answer if I type the correct command. Or maybe someone created a code that does this and I just don't know what to look for.

Especifically, I need to create 3x3 matrices and each variable shoud be in different row. I can also create a matrix and then manipulate it by diving a column by a variable, etc.

Just to put it in context, I use this topic to create matrices and later use them as parametric equations to plot a nomogram. If I have a equation with 3 variables and create a matrix where each variable is in separate rows, I can create a nomogram with 3 axes, where I can choose 2 variables, connect them with a straight line and the place it crosses the third axis is the answer for the equation.

Obviously not every equation can be turned into a matrix, but doing it by trial and error is extremely exhausting and I can't ever be sure if I ran out of possibilities.
(Actually I'm trying to create a matrix of an especific equation and I thought about posting it here, but since I'm not even sure this topic exists, so I thought about creating this question first)

Comment: You might be interested in the companion matrix which has a simple form for the characteristic polynomial associated with it.

Comment: There are many kinds of equations, and indeed you've taken a single "homogeneous" linear equation in three variables and found another homogeneous equation involving a determinant of a $3\times 3$ matrix.  Narrowing what "input" equations you would like to treat in this fashion would help Readers respond cogently.

Comment: This problem can be solved with linear algebra, by obtaining a basis of the kernel (which is 2 dimensional) for the $1 \times 3$ matrix $(1,-2,2)$ and using the theorem that the determinant of a matrix is 0 if its columns are linearly dependent. You don't want the columns to be linearly dependent, since the plane is a 2 dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$, so you can make any "determinant" equation you want with 2 basis vectors of your choice and a third vector of variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Generalization**

Yes.

The determinant traduce the idea of dependance if it is zero, independance elsewhere.

For instance

$$ D=\left|
\begin{array}x
x&0&2\\
y&1&0\\
z&1&1 
\end{array}
\right|=0$$

Means that $$\vec X=
\left(
\begin{array}
xx\\
y\\
z\\
\end{array}
\right),\vec A=
\left(
\begin{array}
00\\
1\\
1\\
\end{array}
\right),\vec B=
\left(
\begin{array}
22\\
0\\
1\\
\end{array}
\right)$$

are dependent (family is not free)

So if you have $$ x+ay+bz=0 \ (1) $$

You can take two vectors $\vec{A}=
\left(
\begin{array}
xa\\
-1\\
0\\
\end{array}
\right)$ and $\vec{B}=
\left(
\begin{array}
xb\\
0\\
-1\\
\end{array}
\right)$ , for which the coordinates satisfies the equation$(1)$

Vector $A$ and $B$ are taken to belong to the plan, and to be independant (it is necessary). So because they belong to the plan defined by the equation. If X belong to the plan, the determinant of X,A,B must be null because vectors are linearly dependant (Because 3 vectors belonging to the same 2 dimensional plan (hyperplan of 3D space))

Develop the determinant, it will give you an equation of the same plan.

**N-th dimension**

You can generalize for $n$ dimensions plans :

Given an hyperplan $H$ of dimension $n$ generated by the equation :

$$x_1+a_2 x_2+a_3 x_3+.....+a_{n} x_{n}=0$$

You will get by taking the $i$ vectors

$$\vec{X_i}=
\left(
\begin{array}
11\\
0\\
.\\
a_i \ \text{at the i-th row}\\
.\\
.\\
0 \\
\end{array}
\right) $$

You get :

$$ det(\vec  X,\vec X_1,...,\vec X_n)=0$$

Which gives an equation of the same plan.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer my question, but I didn't quite follow what you mean. Your answer seems to be on track on what I want and maybe wasn't clear enough on explaining my question.
Thing is, I do not understand how you got vectors A and B for equation 1.

Comment: I extended the anwser

Comment: I understood it now. Thank you. It has really broaden my view on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

If anything, you have to make it a very precise request because you can always rewrite an equation $P(\underline{x})=0$ trivially as
$$
\det\left(
\begin{array}[cc] 
{}P(\underline{x}) & 0 \\ 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)=0
$$
(not to mention the fact that "anything" is the determinant of a $1\times 1$ matrix whose only entry is that"anything").

Comment: I think he means multvariable for plane equations (n dimensional at least)